# Create App using PHP or JavaScript

Tags: php, facebook, tabs, new-operator

Simple question... is it possible to create a new app with php or javascript? Not the app content, but the real app (site url, canvas page, name, secure canvas, etc) and then retrieve the app id and secret for the newly created app. The goal is to be able to clone apps and add the "same" app to different tabs.

Thanks in advance.
Best regards,
Alexandre Mota

Comment: There are file controls with PHP that will allow you to create directories and move/copy files and Javascript could add flair. Perhaps you should expand on your question to make it easier to answer.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you could use iframes.

Answer (score 0):

As far as the docs are concerned, it is NOT possible to do this. They do this intentionally, to control spam.

Reference: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/application/

[Note the second paragraph on that link]